# How to use a php variable inside a form which is a value of innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I want to happen is to display a name. If the user clicks the edit button, a form will appear with with still the name in it.

```js
function edit(firstname){
        document.getElementById("firstname-div").innerHTML='<input type="text" name="firstname" value=firstname>';
      }
```

```html
First name:<div id="firstname-div"><?php echo $firstname ?></div>
      <button type="button" onclick="edit('<?php $firstname ?>')">edit</button><br>
```

I know it has something to do with `value=firstname`. What will be the variable? Is it gonna be `firstname` ?

Comment: _I know it has something to do with value=firstname_ Did  you even try it?

Comment: Yes of course. But firstname is treated as a string.

Comment: You can put the variable like '<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $variableName ?>">'

Comment: Tried that one @subirbiswas. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing "Echo" In your HTMl Code. If you want to use php variable value in client side you need to echo that value

Updated HTML

```
First name:<div id="firstname-div"><?php echo $firstname ?></div>
<button type="button" onclick="edit('<?php echo $firstname ?>')">edit</button><br>
```

Javascript: You need to Use [Javascript Concatenation Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String)

```
function edit(firstname){
    document.getElementById("firstname-div").innerHTML='<input type="text" name="firstname" value="'+firstname+'">';
}
```

Comment: Great! The lack of echo was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use variable in string like this.

Use :

```
document.getElementById("firstname-div")
      .innerHTML='<input type="text" name="firstname" value="'+ firstname +'">';
```

You need to :

```
'+ var +'
```

To concatenate a variable in a string.